# transform: scale causes strange hairline difference in OSX Chrome on Retina screen

Tags: html, css, image, css-transforms

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="listing">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <a class="item" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/560/330/?random">
        </div>
        <div class="title">Item 001</div>
        <div class="date">31 May 2016, 10:30</div>
        <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  // etc...
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.page {
  width: 1100px;
}

/* the 'grid' as you might say */
.listing {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.listing .item-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3));
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 15px 30px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.item .image {
  overflow: hidden;  
}
.item .image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}

.item:hover .image img {
  transform: scale(1.1);  
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.page {
  background: #aaa;  
  width: 1100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* the 'grid' as you might say */
.listing {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.listing .item-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3));
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 15px 30px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.item .image {
  overflow: hidden;  
}
.item .image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}

.item:hover .image img {
  transform: scale(1.15);  
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="listing">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <a class="item" href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/560/330/?random">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Item 001</div>
      <div class="date">31 May 2016, 10:30</div>
      <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <a class="item" href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/560/330/?random">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Item 002</div>
      <div class="date">31 May 2016, 10:35</div>
      <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <a class="item" href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/560/330/?random">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Item 003</div>
      <div class="date">31 May 2016, 10:35</div>
      <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This shows a grid with three items per row. 
The page is 1100px wide, so a row is 1130px wide (because of the negative margins left and right). This means that one item is 1130 / 3 = 376.6666px wide. 
When hovering an item, the image grows to 110%. This causes weird behavior in Chrome: a white hairline appears on one or more sides of the image:

[image]

Or the image overflows its container, despite it's `overflow: hidden` property:

[image]

I've tried to add `.item .image img { will-change: transform; }` but that doesn't make it better.

I suspect it has something to do with the dimensions of `<div class="image">...</div>`: [image]

But I don't know *what* exactly.

Does anyone know how to prevent this kind of subpixel-rounding-artifact?

PS: I'm using Chrome on OSX on a Retina screen.

Comment: I'm unable to see the hairline you are talking about.

Comment: I am using Chrome 50 and I cannot see the hairline.

Comment: Yes, I'm also unable to see that hairline in the code sample, but it's visible in the first screenshot I attached.

Comment: @THiCE Then copy the code of your sample into your project and its done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I think I discovered why this strange behaviour occured!

The markup of the body of page is:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <header class="page-header">
        ...
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="page">
          <div class="listing">
            <div class="item-wrapper">
              <a class="item" href="#">
                <div class="image">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/560/330/?random">
                </div>
                <div class="title">Item 001</div>
                <div class="date">31 May 2016, 10:30</div>
                <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            // etc...
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There was a `z-index` property on the `<main>` element. The strange layout quirks I mentioned above disappeared when I removed the `z-index` property.

I still don't know *why* `z-index` caused that behaviour, but I'm happy it doesn't occur anymore :-)